# Issue SQL statement at the exact same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concurrency, rabbitmq

I'm currently working on a PHP web app and using MySQL (xampp default settings) as my dbms. My problem is that different users could connect to the web app and issue an UPDATE query at the **EXACT** same time.

Here's an example,

The first 10 (info_id 1 to 10) rows of data contains info_update = TRUE

```
For example
**User 1 issue**
UPDATE info SET reply='helloworldOne' WHERE info_id = (SELECT info_id FROM table WHERE info_update = 'TRUE' ORDER BY info_id DESC); 

**User 2 issue**
UPDATE info SET reply='helloworldTwo' WHERE info_id = (SELECT info_id FROM table WHERE info_update = 'TRUE' ORDER BY info_id DESC); 

**User 3 issue**
UPDATE info SET reply='helloworldThree' WHERE info_id = (SELECT info_id FROM table WHERE info_update = 'TRUE' ORDER BY info_id DESC); 

and so on....
```

What I want to do is that all these queries could update to the different rows till info_id (10). So User 11 will automatically issue (done in my code) INSERT query since info_update = TRUE no longer exist in the table.

1) My question is, if these queries are issue to the dbms at the exact same time, will all the above queries update to the same row (info_id)?

2) If the answer on Q1 is no, I'm I right to say that "SELECT info_id FROM table WHERE info_update = 'TRUE' ORDER BY info_id DESC" will generate different info_id in this case instead of info_id (10) for every query?

3) Do I need to use RabbitMQ to queue all these request so that the request gets executed one by one, User 1 request executed then User 2 request executed then User 3 request executed? I'm new to RabbitMQ anyway, so I'm not really sure if RabbitMQ could do this....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MySQL solves these issues internally, meaning that it'll automatically lock the rows being updated, You can read more about it here :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html